# How to send matching fingerprint in iOS XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, ios-ui-automation, xctestcase

I am using xcode 8, swift, and creating a XCTest.  I need to login to the application using a 'fingerprint' via the simulator.  How can I send the option via an XCTest to the XCUIApplication that is normally chosen via the Hardware menu?:

[image]

When the Touch ID prompt is displayed:
[image]